# Why Does This Work? - Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I recently [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443230/vertically-center-responsive-image) where I asked how I may be able to vertically align a responsive image. I found the answer on my own, but it raised an even bigger question because I have no idea how or why it works.

Take a look at this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fmwzT/1/

which uses the following code to vertically align an image in the navbar:

```
<div id="f1"><div id="outer-element"><img id="inner-element" src="http://zx85.dyndns.org/raphtest/img/title.png" alt="Logo"></div></div>
```

```css
#fl {
    float: left;
}

#outer-element {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 301px;
}

#inner-element {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

**However, without Bootstraps newest version (2.3.1) this does not work!**  Take a look at this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fmwzT/2/

This second jsFiddle does not include Boostrap 2.3.1 but DOES contain Boostrap 2.3.0 (contained inside an external css file I called layout.css) and yet it does not work.

**Question:** Does anyone know what part of Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1 is causing the image inside the navbar to be responsive?

Comment: An excellent question. The styles seem to be identical all the way up the DOM.

Comment: @Aaron, that is on purpose to show my point.

Comment: just realized that, redacted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is present in version 2.3.1 (responsive-combined.css) and not in prior versions:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```