# Aligning image within carousel bootstrap 3 css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using a bootstrap carousel example and trying to modify it so I get the center of the larger image within the middle of the carousel to have

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: none;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

<!-- Carousel-->
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x400" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        click <a href="gallery.html">here</a> to visit the gallery
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x400" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/66889_1563569361772_6006784_n.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        click <a href="artists.html">here</a> to visit FoxMind
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

http://prntscr.com/3ommar

basically trying to move this image up so when I add larger images it will always take a part from the center and put that to the carousel

Comment: Here is a good way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443230/vertically-center-responsive-image?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i got what you want!

```
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
 z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
 height: 400px;
 background-color:white;
 }
 .carousel img {
  position: absolute;
   top:auto;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

try it out!Here's a fiddle with it:http://jsfiddle.net/ygF3L/